# Application Request Routing and Throttling

Tags: iis, load-balancing, arr, throttling

We have a set of WCF services that are proxying calls to another web service layer built on top of IBM WebSphere. The WebSphere setup is a black box to us, but we're told that we need to throttle calls to the back-end due to its poor performance and scalability. They also need us to load balance calls to the web server cluster.

My initial thought was to utilize IIS and Application Request Routing (ARR) for load balancing, but the requirement to throttle calls to 50 concurrent requests has me concerned since I don't know how or if this is possible using ARR.

Any thoughts on what the best solution would be?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm not sure if ARR can do this, but I know HAproxy can.

Comment: Thanks, I was also looking at HAproxy so that could be an option.